# How to do 'back' in a div tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a div element in my html and I have a link in it. On clicking this link, I load some other content to the div area using AJAX. The new content has a 'back' link and when user clicks this link I want to show the previous contents in the div area.

I could achieve this by storing the contents to a dummy div before loading the new contents and putting it back when user clicks the back link. Is there a more straight-forward way to achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: You either reload the previous content or cache it. Cache could be like what you said, in a different hidden div maybe, or in a variable.

Comment: you may also store each step in an array hold in localStorage

Answer (score 3):

Put the "previous" contents within a tag, such as a span tag, then hide the previous contents with jQuery on click of the link. Something like...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#black-link').click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
    $('#content').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span id="content">Hi</span>
  <a href="#" id="black-link">Go Back</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But, this is something like what I'm already doing. I was hoping that there is something straightforward available in jquery.